# Change windows installer error message if service installation fails

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

I'm currently struggling with WIX (disclaimer: I'm a very beginner in terms of WIX).

I need to install a service. The specific part of the .wxs file looks like this:

```
<ServiceInstall
        Id="ServiceInstaller"
        Vital="yes"
        Type="ownProcess"
        Name="ABC_MyService"
        DisplayName="TestService"
        Description="Monitoring and management Jobs"
        Start="auto"
        Arguments="--service"
        Account="LocalSystem"
        ErrorControl="normal"
        Interactive="no"
        />
<ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="ABC_MyService" Wait="yes" />
```

Unfortunately the start of the service can fail in some cases (a port is already in use etc.). In that case you will get the super generic and confusing WIX error msg:

> Service *xy* failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges
>   to start system services.

Is there any way to propagate error messages / exceptions which can occur when starting the service and override the generic error msg?

Comment: That's the Windows message for the [Windows Installer error code 1920](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).   While I'm sure that there are language-specific versions of the string, I don't think that it's meant to be overridden in a Windows Installer package (whether built by WiX or not).

Comment: Do you know how to set another error code when running a service? I tried setting service_status.dwWin32ExitCode with another exit code and while the service control panel will actually return the correct error message, the windows installer will just always return the same above mentioned message.

Comment: Are you trying to automate gathering information for support cases in general or are you trying to solve this one case? Or looking at it another way, if you find out the cause in this case, what specific message would show users the experience the same thing in the future that would help them solve the problem themselves?

Comment: The installer will install a service which listens to a specific port. We experienced that this port can be already used in some cases - but instead of showing the user the right error message (port already used - do you want to ignore etc.) the installer will just show this generic message which is really confusing for the user because he has no idea what caused this error. That's the reason for it :-)

Comment: At this point, I can only say that services that can run any code at all typically log abends in the Windows event log.